Collections.binarySearch() using Collections.reverseOrder() as Comparator returns -1
Below program returns search index as -1.The binarySearch should return the location of '50' in the List. However it returns the index as -1.
package com.core.java.collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionsBinarySearch {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         al.add(10);
         al.add(20);
         al.add(30);
         al.add(40);
         al.add(50);

         // The last parameter specifies the comparator
         // method used for sorting.
         int index = Collections.binarySearch(
             al, 50, Collections.reverseOrder());

         System.out.println("Found at index " + index);
 
    }
}


Why would you use a comparator that doesn't match the list's sort order? Of course it won't find the element that way.

As the documentation states "The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the sort(List, Comparator) method), prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined. "

To use Collection.binarySearch(), your data must be sorted by given given comparator. If it is not, then the output will be undefined.
You have given comparator Collections.reverseOrder() , so your data must be sorted in Collections.reverseOrder()
So before binarySearch if you do

Collections.sort(al, Collections.reverseOrder());

and then apply it your answer will be

Found at index 0

which is correct, as data will be : 50,40,30,20,10.

Thank you everyone for your help. I was trying this example from one of the Tutorials where the original data was in reverse order. And it did not have any explanation so I did not understand what is going wrong

@Apama  If this was helpful you should accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left.  Note that if multiple answers are provided, only one may be accepted as the most helpful..
